# Excel VBA How to change format to cells with a comment

Tags: excel, vba, function, comments

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your support.

I am trying to write a VBA code that, when a threaded comment is added to a cell, it changes the cell's text color to better identify it. I must say that I am kind of newbie here so be patient with my lack of knowledge ;)

The approach I have thought of is the following:

1. Define a custom function that checks if a cell has a comment and, if so, returns a value for the function (UPDATED code as suggested by @FunThomas).

```
Public Function CheckCellComment(Target As Range) As Boolean
    CheckCellComment = False
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Target.ThreadedComment Is Nothing Then CheckCellComment = True
End Function
```

2. Use this formula in Conditional formatting to change text color of a given cell in a range.

```
=CheckCellComment=TRUE
```

The result is... nothing.

I have also used the same formula in an adjacent cell:

```
=CheckCellComment(B1)
```

And it always returns "TRUE" regardless of whether the cell (B1) has a comment or not.

I am quite sure I am doing something very basic wrong, but I am unable to find it.

Thanks again.

Comment: You are always checking `cell(1, 1)` (A1) in your function. Probably you mean `If not Target.ThreadedComment Is Nothing...` ?

Comment: By the way, to get a list of all comments in a worksheet, you can do `YourSheet.Comments`. Which is great for looping like `For Each Comment In YourSheet.Comments`. When you have a Comment Object, you can then do `Comment.Parent` to get the cell that the comment is in. Which means to change the color of a commented cell you could do `Comment.Parent.Interior.Color`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try with your suggestions ;)

Comment: I have updated the code replacing 'Cells(1, 1)' by 'Target'. The result is that it always returns TRUE value. It is something related with ThreadedComment, I believe. If I use standard Comment (not threaded) it does work thought. I need to make it work with ThreadedComment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem finally ;)

There was an error in the object *ThreadedComment*, wrong name, must use *CommentThreaded* instead.

I leave the code here for anyone who may need it.

```
Public Function CheckCellComment(Target As Range) As Boolean
    CheckCellComment = False
    Application.Volatile
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Target.CommentThreaded Is Nothing Then CheckCellComment = True
End Function
```

Note that *Application.Volatile* helps updating the formula as you add the comment, but may slow down your sheet.

Thanks for the help.